# How to move 2D camera in OpenGL

Tags: android, camera, opengl-es

I am new in OpenGL, I am making a game in 2D and I want the camera to follow the character.

I started with `gluLookAt()` but I read that I could just move the matrix with `glTranslatef()` and It should do the trick.

The problem is the camera only move the first time It is created but if I increment the X position and Y position It doesn't work. What I m doing wrong? I have incorrect concepts?

I tried it changing to GL_PROJECTION,GL_MODELVIEW, AND GL_TEXTURE,

If I do it on GL_PROJECTION all the items are gone ( thanks to the question answer link I understand that I cant take that way)

If I do it on GL_TEXTURE all the textures start to scroll ( but that is not what i want

If I do it on GL_MODELVIEW just nothing happen all the item are in the same site but if I quit the gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW) line above translatef It move the camera the first iteration and then stop to do it since the last object is on GL10.GL_MODELVIEW

Is at the start at different matrix state?

My render code:

```
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl)
{
    loopStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
    try
    {
        if (loopRunTime < SEngine.GAME_THREAD_FPS_SLEEP)
        {
            Thread.sleep(SEngine.GAME_THREAD_FPS_SLEEP - loopRunTime);
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e)
    {
    }
    deltaTime = (float) ((System.currentTimeMillis() - aRestar)/1000f);


    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.glClearColor((78.0f / 255.0f), (192.0f / 255.0f), (203.0f / 255.0f), 0.0f);

    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
    gl.glTranslatef(x, y, 0f);

    perro.draw(gl);
    palmera.draw(gl);

    comprobacionesColision();
    actualizar(deltaTime);


    x +=0.05f;
    y +=0.05f;

    loopEnd = System.currentTimeMillis();
    loopRunTime = ((loopEnd - loopStart));

}
```

Comment: The code looks right, you are translating your scene each frame to new X/Y, which are +0.5 from previous.

Comment: Yes but if I put glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW) it doesnt work

Comment: IIRC it's recommended to reset the matrix after changing matrix mode. `glLoadIdentity`

Comment: If I put glLoadIdentity before translate it , still nothing happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok after a lot of tries I made it,Stil I dont know if this is the best way to achieve this, if someone can explain why this is a solution it will be good!

I just change the matrix  mode to GL_PROJECTION and translate it

```
gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    gl.glOrthof(0f, 8f, 0f, 4f, -1f, 1f);
    gl.glTranslatef(x, y, 0f);
```

instead of

```
gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
gl.glTranslatef(x, y, 0f);
```